# Retrieving data from a local json file in react

Tags: reactjs

How can i retrieve some data from a local json file i created in my folder? i´m using the following code:

```js
class Intro2 extends Component {
  render() {
    async function getData() {
      const usersData = await fetch("../articles.json");

      const users = await usersData.json();

      return users;
    }
 }
```

This doesn't seem to work for my local json file but if i use a url from git hub users for example its working?

many thanks

The error: main.chunk.js:332 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Only reason I can think of why it's not working is because the directory path is incorrect. Are you sure you have `../articles.json`?

Comment: Yes i do tried many times already with different paths and still not working

Comment: Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @NunoCarro just to make sure, put your articles.json file inside your directory of where your code is  and replace it with `./articles.json` to see if it works. Let me know the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using fetch.
Use import instead. This will ensure webpack doesn't bundle the json file.
But makes it available in the public directory.

```
      const usersData = await import("../articles.json");
```

Fetch will never work because webpack won't `serve` your JSON file.
Not unless you put it in a the static or public folder.

Comment: Thanks Daniel

This seemed to do it.

any other options mentioned above didn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Glad it helped. The other options just didn't give you enough detail.
The other way you can get it to work. Is to move articles.json into /public.
Then change the fetch to be `await fetch("/articles.json");`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're trying to read from your file system you won't be able to do it, because in at least some browsers, you will need to serve the file via a web server process.
But if you are trying to read from http://localhost:9000/articles.json the issue could be another thing.

Comment: I am using localhost, i´ve done npm start and im trying to read from a file instead my src, i tried reading it from public to see if it worked but didnt make any difference..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the `{mode:'no-cors'}` param ?

`fetch('../static/test.txt', {mode: 'no-cors'})`

Else you could simply export it:

`export const json = () => ({...})`

and then import it to your file:
`import {json} from '../json`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `json` is in the project's folder structure.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

import usersData from "../articles.json";

class Intro2 extends React.Component {
    state = {
       usersData: { ...usersData },
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    //  a place for promises
    };

  render() {
    // where the jsx is rendered
    return <div>Renders JSX with state {this.state.usersData.aKey}</div>;
  }
};
```

or with react functional components

```js
// Alternatively,  use  functional components:
import React from "react";

import usersData from "../articles.json";

function Intro2() {
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState({ ...usersData });

  return <div>Renders JSX with state {usersData.aKey}</div>;
}
```